# Python: matplotlib not recognize even when it's installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I am importing matplotlib into my python script as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I have matplotlib installed on my machine and I did it through the command prompt. It's located in the folder

```
C:\Users\Br. David Klecker\Downloads\WPy-3701\python-3.7.0.amd64\Lib\site-packages
```

This is the error I am getting from the IDLE screen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I could have sworn this was working yesterday, so the fact that it is not working today is strange. Can anyone provide a hint so to how this could have changed or if there is something I may have overlooked?

Comment: look at the output of `pip list` or `conda list`, whatever you're using, and look for matplotlib in it. Do you have multiple interpreters installed? If so check the others.

Comment: matplotlib 2.2.2 is present in the output of pip list. not sure how to check if multiple interpreters are installed.

Answer (score 1):

This issue here is I had two python interpreters installed on the computer. I deleted the one where matplotlib was not present and the issue is now cleared.